# About some property of a subspace of a prime sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Let an Euclidean space $V$ be a prime sum of two  subspaces (not necessarilly orthogonal)
$$
(1) \ \ \  V=V_1 \oplus  V_2.
$$

Edit

Let $L \subset V$ be an arbitrary subspace in  $V$ such that for each $x=x_1+x_2\in V=V_1 \oplus V_2$ we have $\|x_1\|=\|x_2\|$.

According to (1) we have $L \subset L_1\oplus L_2$, where $L_1=\{p_1(x): x\in L\}$, $L_2=\{p_2(x):x\in L\}$, $p_1, p_2$ are projections on components of prime sum (1).

I wish to prove that for each $a\in L_1$ there exists exactly one $b\in L_2$ such that $a+b\in L$.

Hope, it is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily true: Consider $V_1={\rm span}(1,0)$, $V_2={\rm span}(0,1)$, and $L={\rm span}(1,2)$, so if $a=(1,0)$ then the only possible $b$ are $(0,\pm1)$, but it's clear that $a+b\notin L$.

Comment: Thanks. The question is not correct. I will try to reformulate it.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. This is still not true: Take $V_1={\rm span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$, $V_2={\rm span}(0,0,1)$, and $L={\rm span}(1,0,1)$. Then $a=(0,1,0)$ would be a counterexample.